# retrieve video (categoryID) from youtube using json

Tags: android, json, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

i want to upload youtube videos from my app and find those videos after.

to do so i uploaded the videos using [v3 youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

here is part of the code that use to add title, description Etc.

```
 snippet.setTitle("Test Upload via Java on " + cal.getTime());
      snippet.setDescription(
          "Video uploaded via YouTube Data API V3 );

      // Set your keywords.
      List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
      tags.add("test");
      tags.add("example");
      tags.add("java");
      tags.add("YouTube Data API V3");
      tags.add("erase me");
      snippet.setTags(tags);
```

i want to add catagotyid so i just add :

```
snippet.setCategoryId("test");
```

in this moment the upload code stop to work, why ?

[to retrieve all the video that upload by my app i need to fill in part line "snippet" (without Quotes) and in id line add my category id like "test" (without Quotes),
and then result  catch by json ?](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list)

UPDATE :

How should I fill the ["try it!"](http://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#try-it) ? to recieve list of catagoryID, And assume that I got the list, how do I know which category to choose?, I think I'm missing something and I do not know what

Answer (score 0):

Try a GET request on this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=US&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Of course you replace the `{YOUR_API_KEY}` with your key. You should get back something like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Fn7tolrWrLXf7uknBpwCU9OfMA8/jOw8Jx4EQq_udW-0UgiRcCMWqWQ\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "1",
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"Fn7tolrWrLXf7uknBpwCU9OfMA8/gljmmWdkbtlCrMi74KVYLrbTaIA\"",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Film & Animation"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "2",
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"Fn7tolrWrLXf7uknBpwCU9OfMA8/n1RtRMaPpKgph8MvS9wf742Tm5U\"",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Autos & Vehicles"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "10",
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"Fn7tolrWrLXf7uknBpwCU9OfMA8/1LzYK9Uf9Nt0hzBqNqhuHw0LPI0\"",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Music"
   }
  },
```